# Which rxjs operator is more suitable to get value from two observables although only one not emitted?

Tags: angular, rxjs

I have two `FormControl`:

```
  criteria = new FormControl('');
  term = new FormControl('');
```

I using combine to get the last value emitted from those values.

```
  @Output() change = combineLatest([this.term.valueChanges, this.criteria.valueChanges]).pipe(
    map((r) => {
      return r.join(' ');
    })
  );
```

The problem is only when two values are emitted then `change` is emit.

Which rxjs operator more suitable to trigger the change when one of the observables are emitted or both?

[Codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/tender-shockley-bsk8c?file=/src/app/app.module.ts)

Comment: combineLatest will emit when any observable emits, the one that hasn't emitted yet will be undefined

Comment: are you sure? see my example, (at control.log): https://codesandbox.io/s/tender-shockley-bsk8c?file=/src/app/app.module.ts

Comment: I was wrong, see my answer, I added a startsWith

Comment: https://rxjs.dev/api/operators/combineLatestWith

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can stick a startsWith in to make sure they emit before keystroke

```js
const { of, combineLatest } = rxjs;
const { startWith, delay } = rxjs.operators;

combineLatest([
  of(1).pipe(startWith(0), delay(1000)),
  of(2).pipe(startWith(0), delay(500))
]).subscribe(val => {
  console.log(val);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/rxjs/6.6.3/rxjs.umd.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: I add `startWith`: `.pipe( startWith(['', '']), map(r => r.join(' ')));`, still the problem exist.

Comment: make each control start with[this.term.valueChanges.pipe(startWith('')), this.criteria.valueChanges.pipe(startWith(''))]

Answer (score 2):

Use something like this. You can don't use messages from valueChanges.

```
merge(this.term.valueChanges, this.criteria.valueChanges).pipe(
    map(() => {
      return [this.term.value, this.criteria.value].join();
    })
  );
```

Comment: merge is deprecated

Comment: maybe I use deprecated signature, but merge is not deprecated. I sure. Try `merge([observable1, observable2])`